# Options for "Close" > "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"

Tags: support

When I do "Close" > "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", the only option I get is "Economics Meta" (see screenshot below).

Shouldn't there be other options?

(I'm not sure if this is a bug that only I am experiencing.)

[image: "]

Comment: I just tried and have the same. I agree that there should be more options. Stats, math and OR spring to mind. Of course one can always suggest that in a comment. Perhaps it's because we're (still :( ) in beta?

Answer (score 3):

Mods are able to migrate questions properly. For the time being just flag the question and let us know what site we should migrate it to.